# ROS Answers SE migration: Commenting

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Nate,

I'm not sure whether this is a bug specific to my account, but I'm not able to comment on anyone's posts, all I can do is post a new answer or comment on my own posts. Is there a way for you to fix this?

Thanks,
Thomas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/47/commenting/) by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 508 on 2012-10-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-10-18**:
hmm. let me look into that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It should be fixed now.

---

Originally posted by [natepak](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/57/natepak/) with karma: 111 on 2012-10-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0